# Parsing Java String Special Character Error

Tags: java, regex, string

I  want to parse a string in order to get the value  of an attribute.For example i have the following String: 
     **calling_number=+385317KFWVM, call_direction=I, conversation_duration=29,**

Each attribute and its value is separated by commas.I have declared the name and the type of each attribute in a class named MessageBean.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

 try {
        MessageBean attributes_bean =  MessageBean.parse("calling_number=+385317KFWVM, call_direction=I, conversation_duration=29,");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public class MessageBean {

    private String calling_number;
    private String call_direction;
    private int conversation_duration;

    public static MessageBean parse(String line) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageBean bean = new MessageBean();
        line = URLDecoder.decode(line, "utf-8");
        bean.setCalling_number(MessageBean.getParameter(line, "calling_number"));
        bean.setCall_direction(MessageBean.getParameter(line, "call_direction"));
        bean.setConversation_duration(Integer.parseInt(MessageBean.getParameter(line, "conversation_duration")));

    return bean;
    }

    private static String getParameter(String line, String name) {
        String value = "";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(name + "=([^,]*),");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            value = m.group(1);
        }

       return value;
    }

}
```

I expect my result to be **+385317KFWVM, I, 29** .

Instead i get **385317KFWVM, I, 29** which means that i miss the + sign.I understand that there is a problem with my regular expression.I have tried everything like \+ but i still don't get the right results.Any help?

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. It looks like it's *just* about the regular expression, so all you need is a `main` method that creates a `Pattern`, matches it against a hard-coded string, and reports the results. That will be a lot easier to help you with, and more valuable to future readers too.

Comment: And if that doesn't show the issue, check that the string value being passed around really does have the + in it. The answer from L.S looks very plausible. This is the sort of thing you should check with diagnostic (logging, a debugger) *before* posting on Stack Overflow. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I am new to the StackOverflow community.I will follow you advice Jon Skeet.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run URLDecoder.decode(line, "utf-8") the + is removed from your string.

Comment: You re right!I removed the line decoder and it works fine.Thanks a lot!